# Прерывание отправки формы

Tags: jquery, ajax, форма

Есть скрипт проверки формы перед отправкой.

```
$("form#new_mail").submit(function(){
        var to = trimBoth($("input[name=\"to\"]",this).val());
        var topic = trimBoth($("input[name=\"topic\"]",this).val());
        var content = trimBoth($("textarea[name=\"content\"]",this).val());

        if (to.length <= 0) {
            alert("Не заполнено поле \"Кому:\"!");
            return false;
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: {action:"check_block", login:to},
                success: function(resp){
                    if (resp=="blocked") { 
                        alert("Вы не можете писать данному мпользователю!");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            })

        }
        if (topic.length < 3 || topic.length > 50) {
            alert("Введите тему письма (от 3 до 50 символов)!");
            return false;
        }
        if (content.length < 5) {
            alert("Введите текст сообщения (не менее 5 символов)!");
            return false;
        }
    })
```

Проблема в том, что когда выполняется условие в ajax **`(resp=="blocked")`** выводится алерт, а **`return false;`** не срабатывает, выполняется следующая проверка (topic.length).

Подскажите как вернуть false для формы, а не для success function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть так (**UPDATE** 2011-12-07 12:48):

```
$("form#new_mail").submit(function(){
        var to = trimBoth($("input[name=\"to\"]",this).val());
        var topic = trimBoth($("input[name=\"topic\"]",this).val());
        var content = trimBoth($("textarea[name=\"content\"]",this).val());
        var rc = true;

        if (to.length <= 0) {
            alert("Не заполнено поле \"Кому:\"!");
            rc = false;
        }
        else {
            var resp = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                async: false,
                data: { action: "check_block", login: to },
            }).responseText;

            if (resp == "blocked") {
                alert("Вы не можете писать данному мпользователю!");
                rc = false;
            }
        }
        if (rc) {
            if (topic.length < 3 || topic.length > 50) {
                alert("Введите тему письма (от 3 до 50 символов)!");
                rc = false;
            }
            if (content.length < 5) {
                alert("Введите текст сообщения (не менее 5 символов)!");
                rc = false;
            }
        }
        return rc;
});
```

Comment: то же самое, форма не отправляется, но проверка следующего условия все равно происходит.

Comment: не, в таком случае проверку проходят все условия кроме `if (to.length <= 0)`, и соответственно выскакивает аж 3 алерта

Comment: Еще можно сделать как-то так:

    var resp = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        async: false,
        data: { action: "check_block", login: to },
    }).responseText;
    if (resp == "blocked") {
        alert("Вы не можете писать данному мпользователю!");
        rc = false;
    }

Comment: О, отлично, так работает! Спасибо!

P.S. Не знал про **`responseText`**

Answer (score 1):

потому что success вызовится если ответ от сервера будет 200. так что return false; ничего не изменит, 
на сервере лучше проверять и отдавать ошибки типа 404 и тп и ловить колбэками типа statusCode или onError

Comment: сервер 200 и возвращает, но мне при 200-м статусе надо прервать форму.